# Access controls inside listbox c# (windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

```
         my xaml  code..
      <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1" >
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Height="150"            Width="500" >
            <Grid Width="500" Height="150" Background="White" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.9*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Name="imgitem"  Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Source="{Binding ImgSource}" Margin="0,5,4,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtbindprice"  Text="{Binding _PRICE,ConverterCulture=en-IN,StringFormat=C}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.Column="1"  Width="350"  Foreground="Black" Height="60" Margin="40,70,20,-10"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtFinalTotal"  Text="{Binding _FinalTotal}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.Column="1"  Width="350"  Foreground="Red" Height="60" Margin="40,115,20,-10"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtITMNAME"  Text="{Binding _ITMNAME }" Padding="1"  Tap="ItmName_Tapped" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"  FontWeight="Normal" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"  Foreground="OrangeRed" Width="Auto"  Height="150"  Margin="30,25,10,-10"/>
                <CheckBox  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="Black" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="Red" Margin="10,20,-15,10"  Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_UnChecked"  /> 

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

     <ListBox Height="Auto" Name="lstbxmanual" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1 }"  Width="475" Margin="2,192,0,-39" Background="White"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    </ListBox>
```

I  want  to  access  textblocks  inside  listbox  based on  selected  index

```
accessing textblock 
  string  a =txtbindprice.text
```

wont  work  as they  are  inside  data  template  of  listbox..

I  came  across  visual  child  tree  methods  and  some  other  examples..i  cant  find  much  info..

please  help  me  regarding  this...

Comment: Why visual child tree methods didn't work for you? have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18441797/1648849) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15191380/1648849)?

Comment: which  one  is  better  based on  my requirement??

Comment: I'll update my answer based on those.

Comment: thank  you ..please  be  specific..it  will be  useful  for  my  learning purpose..

Answer (score 0):

The following method finds currently selected list-box item:

```
    private ListBoxItem FindSelectedListBoxItem(DependencyObject control)
    {
        int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
        for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
            FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
            // Not a framework element or is null
            if (fe == null) return null;

            if (child is ListBoxItem && ((ListBoxItem)child).IsSelected)
            {
                // Found the control so return
                return (ListBoxItem)child;
            }

            else
            {
                // Not found it - search children
                ListBoxItem nextLevel = FindSelectedListBoxItem(child);
                if (nextLevel != null)
                    return nextLevel;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Below method finds any child control with a certain name from a given root control:

```
private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
{
    int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
    for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
        FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
        // Not a framework element or is null
        if (fe == null) return null;

        if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
        {
            // Found the control so return
            return child;
        }
        else
        {
            // Not found it - search children
            DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
            if (nextLevel != null)
                return nextLevel;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now you can use the first method to get currently selected `ListBoxItem`and then pass it to the second method to retrieve any control inside this `ListBoxItem` (e.g. `txtbindprice`):

```
ListBoxItem item = FindSelectedListBoxItem(this);
TextBlock txtPrice = FindChildControl<TextBlock>(item , "txtbindprice") as TextBlock;
string a = txtPrice.Text;
```

**Update**

You can add `SelectionChanged` event to your `ListBox` like this:

```
 <ListBox Height="Auto" Name="lstbxmanual" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
</ListBox>
```

And then retrieve a certain `TextBlock.Text` (e.g. `txtbindprice`) this way:

```
public void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ListBoxItem item = FindSelectedListBoxItem((ListBox(sender)));
    TextBlock txtPrice = FindChildControl<TextBlock>(item , "txtbindprice") as TextBlock;
    string a = txtPrice.Text;
}
```

Comment: iam looking  for  a  procedure  which  gets  values of all  textblocks  inside  listbox....i  have  more than  100  index in listbox  to  select...

Comment: Still you don't have to get it from `txtbindprice.text`. If your `ListBox` has an `ItemsSource` you can get each `_PRICE` from this `ItemsSource` through a loop that iterates 100 times.

Comment: index  of items  in  my listbox     will be  varied ,as  i   am  implementing  search  feature   for  the  listbox..  so   items  source  mismatches  some  times..

Comment: i  have  a  bunch  of  items  in  listbox....  its  retrieving   mismatched  data..  how   to  get  accurate  data  based  on  selecteditem  index

Comment: What do you mean? `this` inside `FindSelectedListBoxItem(this)` is an instance of your main window or if you're using this method inside `selectionChanged` event, you could use `(ListBox)sender` instead.

Comment: @Kartiikeya if by "FindSelectedListBoxItem(this) consists of?" you mean "where is the body of this method?" then It's right here (the first method in my answer).

Comment: does   FindSelectedListBoxItem(this)    sholud  be  placed   inside  vent  handler  of   listbox  or  any  other  control..?? @bahram

Comment: the  code  inside  OnSelectionChanged   event, i  need  to    use  that  particular code for  checkbox  checked  event  ..  errror  in dependence  object  for  check  box.  it s only  returning  first  value...please  help...